# LoganSquare not including field name on generated Json

Tags: android, logan-square

I have a class `DbRecord`

```
public class DbRecord {


    @JsonField(name="on_duties")
    List<OnDutyElement> onDuties;

    @JsonField(name = "date_time")
    DateTime dateTime;
```

When I try to serialize an object of this class, the LoganSquare doesn't include the dateTime field.

Generated JSON: `{:"2015-12-21T11:32:17.503-05:00","on_duties":[{...everything normal from here`

Comment: this looks more like a bug in LoganSquare then in you code. you should probably submit a bugreport on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, there is a bug. 
Write your own `TypeConverter` that extends `DateTypeConverter`, override `serialize()` method explicit pass `writeFieldName` with value `true`.

This will force the type converter write field name to the writer.

Comment: I was using `jsonGenerator.writeString` instead of `jsonGenerator.writeStringField` in my `TypeConverter`.

Answer (score 4):

If all JSON Field names are lowercase with underscore you can define fieldNamingPolicy like that.

```
@JsonObject(fieldNamingPolicy = JsonObject.FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
public class DbRecord {


@JsonField
List<OnDutyElement> onDuties;

@JsonField
DateTime dateTime;
```

You need also to have TypeConverter for DateTime if you haven't done that already, LoganSquare allows you now to define the TypeConverter in the JsonField Annotation like that

```
 @JsonField(typeConverter = DateTimeConverter.class)
DateTime time;
```

and the DateTimeConverter

```
public class DateTimeConverter implements TypeConverter<DateTime> {
@Override
public DateTime parse(JsonParser jsonParser) throws IOException {
    String dateString = jsonParser.getValueAsString(null);
    try {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateString);
        return dateTime.changeTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), TimeZone.getDefault());
    } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        runtimeException.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void serialize(DateTime object, String fieldName, boolean writeFieldNameForObject, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField(fieldName, object.format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"));
}
```

}